# Find 5 zero divisors of $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find 5 zero divisors of $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}$.

So far, I have found the zero divisors of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ as follows:

First, note that the non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ are $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. Now, check for the various possibilities. Note that $2 \times 3 = 3 \times 2 \equiv 3 \times 4 = 4 \times 3 \equiv 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$. This gives that the zero divisors of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ are $\{2, 3, 4\}$. This is where am getting stuck. I can't adopt a similar process to find the zero divisors of $\mathbb{Z}$, of course. How should I proceed?

Comment: How is multiplication in $\mathbb Z_6 \times \mathbb Z$ defined?

Comment: You seem to be assuming for $(a,b)$ to be a zero divisor that $a$ must be a $0$ divisor of $\mathbb Z_6$ and $b$ must be a zero divisor of $\mathbb Z$.  Why are you assuming that?  Also $(0, x) \ne 0$

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I was erroneously assuming that and the multiplication is defined component-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(a,0)$ with $a \neq 0$ can be a zero divisor as well. Because with $b \neq 0$, we can have $(a,0) \times (0,b)=(0,0)$ (assuming componentwise multiplication)

Comment: Ah, I see! That gives the answer to my question immediately, I didn't even need to engage in the work that I did. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain how elements like $(2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)$ can also be valid zero divisors here?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson $(2,2) \times (3,0)=(0,0)$. Now try similar idea for the remaining pairs.